# Plot multiple individual by one function?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

Could you please help me to solve this problem:

I have a database like below:

```
Animal  Milk    Age
1   11.96703591 1
1   13.41236333 2
1   14.85769075 3
1   16.30301817 4
2   17.74834559 1
2   19.08465881 2
2   20.42097204 3
2   14.66094662 4
2   14.70197368 5
3   14.74300075 1
3   14.78402781 2
3   14.82505488 3
3   14.86608194 4
3   14.90710901 5
```

I want to make a plot between milk versus age, so I use function plot(Milk~Age, data=mydata)
My question is how can I make the same plot (Milk~Age) for each individual, by using only one function. Since I have about 200 animals and if I have to run 200 times to produce 200 curves.

Thanks
Phuong

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use library `ggplot2` and then make individual facets for each animal. As you have many animals you can change `ncol=` or `nrow=` in `facet_wrap()` to get better view.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,y=Milk))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~Animal)
```

[image]

Comment: hey didzis, is there a way to write each separate facet into a separate pdf file?   pls see OP's misplaced comment below my answer

Answer (score 1):

The following code should create as many plot as you have unique `Animal` values, and store them in different pdf files in the working directory :

```
invisible(by(df, df$Animal, function(tmpdf) {
    pdf(paste0("plot",tmpdf$Animal[1],".pdf"))
    plot(Milk~Age, data=tmpdf, main=tmpdf$Animal[1])
    dev.off()
}))
```

Comment: I have not tried the second suggestion, but I think it fits my idea. I will try it when I get home, then see if it works. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use ggplot from the ggplot2 package

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,y=Milk, color=Animal))+geom_point()
```

edit1: actually this would lose clarity with 200 animals. Did you want all this data point in one graph or spread out across 200 graphs?  If the latter then I agree with Didzis

Comment: Hi Didzis, I tried you approach and it fits my idea. Thanks. However, I still have problem of how to separate plot for each animal to each pdf file/page or image. Since I have a bout 200 animals, then if we put in the same pdf page, it is just so so small.

Comment: I think you meant to post it under a different answer. but from my perspective, if you want to generate a new pdf for each animal, you may have to write a loop

Comment: @hn.phuong If you need separate pdf of each animal then you don't need to use facet_wrap() but just need to adapt juba answer with ggplot() or use loop.